# Disable Anti-aliasing on WinForms text rendering

Tags: c#, winforms, text, rendering

I'm developing an application in WinForms C#, and the designer is forcing me to use Anti-Aliased text. Aliased text is a requirement in the application, although there is no obvious way to set the text rendering mode.

If you're curious, the application is a small simulation app designed to look and feel as if you were using Windows 95.

How do I disable text anti-aliasing?

Comment: Hi Pang, I just edited my post to clarify my question. Thank you, AShifter.

Comment: Are you talking about normal text on controls or about text you draw yourself with GDI+? The former is a system-wide setting but the latter can be set in the Graphics object. So, it looks as if you will have to owner-draw all controls..? Simple for most, not so simple for others.. (I hope you need no RTBs or TextBoxes..!)

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about text on controls. It's fine, I'll try to go without it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In program.cs, there is a flag `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`. When this value is set to true, it seems to disable anti-aliasing and gives me the result I need.

Comment: For me, this is already set to false, and text has antiliasing. Setting it to true didn't work either.